# NSG rules not replicated using Azure site recovery fail over

Tags: virtual-machine, replication, network-security-groups, azure-site-recovery

1. I have recently replicated my Azure VM using Azure site recovery and performed a test failover. I was disappointed to see the NSG rules, route table not reflected from Source to target. If the network settings aren't reflected from source to target I don't think so it is of use using Site recovery. Am I missing any steps? I have also created "Allow 443 port outbound rule" for source NSG.
2. How to Create outbound HTTPS (443) rules for the Site Recovery IPs that correspond to the source location: Location-East US, Site Recovery IP address-13.82.88.226, Site Recovery monitoring IP address-104.45.147.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Site Recovery does not create NSGs as part of the failover operation. It's recommended to create the required Azure NSGs **before initiating failover**. You can then associate NSGs to failed over VMs automatically during failover, using automation scripts with Site Recovery’s powerful [recovery plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-create-recovery-plans). You could get more info about [Azure to Azure replication with NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/concepts-network-security-group-with-site-recovery#azure-to-azure-replication-with-nsg).
2. For Azure VM replication, ensure that the NSG rules on the source Azure region allow [outbound connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-about-networking#outbound-connectivity-for-ip-address-ranges).

   Like [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-about-networking#outbound-connectivity-for-ip-address-ranges) NSG configuration. Please note, you need to create an outbound HTTPS (443) rules for the Site Recovery IPs that correspond to the target location in the source NSG, but create an outbound HTTPS (443) rules for the Site Recovery IPs that correspond to the source location in the target NSG.

   In this case, you want to create outbound HTTPS (443) rules for the Site Recovery IPs that correspond to the source location: Location-East US, Site Recovery IP address-13.82.88.226, Site Recovery monitoring IP address-104.45.147.24, it will like this:
   [image]